# PWABuilder Android Package "Cannot find System Java Compiler."

Tags: android

I get this error on project build

> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK
>   (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to
>   point to the according directory.

The problem is that I only got this with the project provided by PWABuilder, native android projects works normally.

If someone knows what is going on, please tell me.

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME system variable? Check by `java -v` on cmd. It should display the java version you have.

Comment: It is there I checked it, with native android projects, I don't have any problem.